# 90s Novel Capitalizing On Jurassic Park

Tags: story-identification, novel, jurassic-park

This novel was clearly trying to pull from the goodwill Jurassic Park had generated.  It starts with a scientist or engineer who is building some sort of dinosaur (maybe hologram or virtual reality).  In the first chapter he is poisoned and imagines the dinosaurs are real as he starts to die.  A detective comes in. He is led around the company by a female employee. He ultimately determines the murder was an accident and the female employee asks if all his cases end so stupidly.  I read this in 94 or 95. It might be part of a series.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10240235-the-dinosaur-feather is too late in time, and features an actual murder, but I figured I should mention it.

Comment: No, I definitely read it pre-1997 and post-1994. So it can't be later than '97.  Was part of a series featuring the investigator. The engineer working on the dinosaurs was killed by poison out in the bathroom soap. The janitor out it there to kill someone else, his rival in a live triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be: [Night of the Carnotaurus](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/b-b-calhoun/night-of-carnotaurus.htm) ? It is part of Dinosaur Detective series and it came out in 1995.

> When Fenton Rumplemayer's father goes to Hollywood for a week as a technical consultant on a dinosaur film, Fenton accompanies him and discovers strange mistakes and accidents plaguing the movie studio.

Comment: Seems somewhat unlikely to me. Those books seem to have a kid protagonist and seem a bit softer in tone than people dying.

Comment: I agree, but that is what I found. The others all have dinosaur detectives - detectives which are dinosaurs! Damn you, Google.

Comment: U don't think that is it. It was an adult book. I don't remember a child being involved, or illustrations. Thanks though!